# "Variation" is a required field

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am creating a farmhouse website, farmhouses will be available for rent and for purchasing. for that, I am writing my own product url.

```
<a href="/cart/?add-to-cart=4881&variation_id=5020">Checkout Now</a>
```

there are only 2 variations and they have price and they are "in-stock"

when I go to url it shows error on cart page

```
"Purchase type is a required field"
```

where *Purchase type* is the attribute on which variations are created.

What is mean by "is a required field" when the required field (regular price) is filled.

Comment: When posting on Stack Overflow, try to provide code to get support on your question.

Comment: What are you doing to process the `variation_id` variable in the URL? 98% sure WooCommerce doesn't handle that automatically. hence, it doesn't know what attributes you've defined.

Comment: ok I understood that so I changed the url with 
`<a href="/cart/?add-to-cart=4881&variation_id=5020&purchase-type=cash-purchase">Checkout Now</a> ` 
which did not return any error but would work if I have given valid variation ID. since each variation of each product have a unique id so I am not able to hard code that.

What I am now searching is the way to get 1st and 2nd variation id in the php variable so that I can use 
`/cart/?add-to-cart=4881&variation_id=<? php echo $variation_id_number; ?>&purchase-type=cash-purchase>Checkout</a> `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem became to be a solution for another problem which is

**How to create your own product page**

after too much searching, I found out a function `$product->get_available_variations() ;`
which returns an array of available variations and their attributes. and got product id from `$product->get_id();` .

I used `$pro_vari[0][attributes] [attribute_pa_ptfc];` to get my custom attribute slug and then used it to get exact `variable_id` for the variation by

`$ft_variation_id=  $pro_vari[0][variation_id] ;`

in last I created an add to cart url which directly took me to the checkout (skipping cart page)

`<a href="/checkout/?add-to-cart=<?php echo $current_product_id; ?>&variation_id=<?php echo $ft_variation_id; ?>&attribute_pa_ptfc=finance-terms">Checkout Now</a>`

this created following link:

`checkout/?add-to-cart=4881&variation_id=5022&attribute_pa_ptfc=finance-terms`

In my case I only have 2 variations so used IF condition for `pro_var[0]`  and `pro_vari[1]`